# Projection from 2D Camera view to 2D Bird Eye view

Tags: graphics, camera, computer-vision

I have, let's say, a 2D RGB image from a camera. Then I draw a point on it, defined by two parameters, `x` and `y`.

[image: Camera view]

In a bird-eye view, I want to project a line in order to represent all the possible places where this point is (since I do not have distance information). I would actually need the `x` value only, since I am only interested in such line and `y` or the point's height does not provide me any important information for bird-eye view.

That would be the result I am looking for:

[image: Bird-eye view]

I have the camera aperture and I already tried working with it, but I still do not get the necessary transformation to obtain the angle where the line is. Could anyone help me? Thank you.

Edit: I know the position of the camera (let's say is the origin, (0,0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need camera `FOVx` or `focal_length` (sometimes referred as `znear`), let assume screen (resolution `xs*ys`) centered perspective projection:

[image: FOVx 3D]

From that the angle is just matter of simple goniometrics:

[image: FOVx 2D]

so relation between `FOVx` and `focal_length`:

```
FOVx = atan(xs/(2*focal_length))
focal_length = xs/(2*tan(FOVx))
```

and finally your angle `ang` from `x`:

```
ang = atan( (x - (xs/2)) / focal_length )
```

In case you just want to convert `(x,y,z)` into your bird's eye view `(x',y')` exploit triangle similarity:

```
x' = z + focal_length
y' = (ys'/2) + (x-(xs/2))*focal_length/z
```

where `xs'*ys'` is the resolution of your birdseye view. However its usual to render up to far plane (or up to some visibility) not just up to near plane ...  in such case just offset the `z'` to match your wanted range.

Comment: Nice explanation. Thank you!